# Turn one Replicated server into Observer

Tags: .net, ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.7.6. I use several servers and I want to turn one of them into an observer, the server that doesn't process any queries, it just synchronizes data with others. All the caches are in Replicated mode.

I thought that it can be done with AffinityFunction by assigning this observer to partition 1 when others belong to the partition 0, and returning partition 0 for all the requested keys in GetPartition(object key) of IAffinityFunction.

But this didn't work for me: queries are done in this observer server despite it belongs to partition 1.

Can somehow this be done in Ignite?

Comment: Can you describe the use case in more detail? What is the purpose of such a server that does not process queries?

Comment: I want to do backups: this observer wakes up, synchronizes, stops Ignite, archives its work folder and waits until the next backup. I this server performs queries when it is not fully synchronized it leads to unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to disable queries like this for a single server in Ignite.

Instead, for the described "periodic backup" scenario, I would advise using a client node:

- Wake up, start Ignite client node (`IgniteConfiguration.ClientMode = true`)
- Iterate over cache data and write it to disk in a format of your choice:

```cs
var cache = ignite.GetCache<K, V>(cacheName);
using (var file = File.OpenWrite(...))
{
  foreach (ICacheEntry<K, V> entry in cache)
  {
    file.Write(Serialize(entry));  
  }
}
```

Advantages over a server node solution:

- Does not cause Ignite rebalance and other overhead that newly joined server node causes within the cluster
- More compact backups: work folder contains WAL, metadata and other system stuff that is not necessary to back up

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But the problem is in that the data backed up in the way I propose is restored in a very simple way, naturally for Ignite. I just start the backup node and server node and all the data restores from backup to the server node. 
Your solution needs a new backup system and this system backs up the objects sequentially, which can lead to unwanted effects.
I just want to unlink backup node from being queried, this will do backup process simple and reliable